# How to make a Objective-C Statically Linked frameworks to support Swift import

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I have made an Objective-C Statically Linked framework by this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2430-how-to-create-a-framework-for-ios) for two years ago. Now I need to support Swift impot for my framework. What can I do?

```
import MySDK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve my problem.

Add a `module.modulemap` file to your library project.

```
framework module MySDK {
  umbrella header "MySDK.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }
}
```

And add the this script snippet to your `Run Scripts` of `Aggregate` target.

```
# Support module map
dst=${MY_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION}/Modules/
mkdir -p "${dst}"
cp "/Path/To/module.modulemap" "$dst"
```

The script snippet would add a directory and copy the module map file to your framework.